# How to initialize 3 Dimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

How to initialize three dimensional array in C#?

Comment: Google! `int[, ,] arr = new int[1, 2, 3];`

Answer (score 3):

```
string[,,] strArray = new string[3,3,3];
strArray[1,1,1] = "test";
strArray[0,0,1] = "World";
strArray[0,0,0] = "Hello";
```

IIRC